# A and B are independent events with $P(A)=.4$ and $P(B)=.5$, determine $P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability

If A and B are independent events and $P(A) = .4$ and $P(B) = .5$, determine $P(A\cup B)$.

I did $P(A \cap B) = .4 + .5 = .9$
and since $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$
$P(A\cup B) = .4 + .5 -.9$
Will it be $0$?

I think it's wrong...

Comment: **Hint**: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) $

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.

Comment: I did, P(A)P(B) = (.4)(.5)=(.2), and plugging it into the formula.. I got (.4)+(.5)-(.2) = .7, hopefully thats right

Comment: Indeed it is.$\ $